# Using \def to output boolean true/false values - Usage in Tasks Package "Resume" Function

Tags: etoolbox, preamble, tasks

I am attempting to use a `\def` (or any equivalent) to give a boolean output, but unable to do so. Compilation of below results in the following error:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tasks}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tasks}(1)
        \task 1
        \task 2
        \end{tasks}

    \def \trueBool {true}

    \begin{tasks}[resume = \trueBool](1)
        \task 1
        \task 2
        \end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Of course replacing `\trueBool` with a literal 'true' value, as in: `\begin{tasks}[resume = true]` works as expected.

This is needed as I need to pass in a variable true/false based on another condition being true elsewhere.

Hoping someone knows how to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own key:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { tasks/list }
 {
  resume? .code:n  = \exp_args:Nne \keys_set:nn { tasks/list } { resume = #1 },
  resume? .default:n = \trueBool,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\trueBool}{true}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(1)
\task 1
\task 2
\end{tasks}

Some text in between

\begin{tasks}[resume?](1)
\task 1
\task 2
\end{tasks}

Some text in between

\renewcommand\trueBool{false}

\begin{tasks}[resume?](1)
\task 1
\task 2
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]